# $mail->Send() send multiple email using PHPMailer class

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

> using PHPMailer class. 
>   I have following code. for email send to client and owner same email,
>   only **Send from** information is change for **client and owner**. 
>   Blockquote
>   when i  submit email information ,client get double email(get 2 email) and owner get 1 email.
>   and client get email from client information  how can send individual
>   email to both.
>   is this code contain any error?

```
/* for client email send*/   
    $emailAddr ='owneremail@gmail.com';
         $body             = $client_message;
            $body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);    
            $mail->SetFrom(c, $name);    
            $mail->AddAddress($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);    
            $mail->Subject    = "subject1";    
            $mail->MsgHTML($body);
            $mail->AddAttachment("images/download.pdf"); 



if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    /*For owner email*/    
    $client_message1 = $client_message;
    $body             = $client_message1;
    $body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);    
    $mail->AddAddress($emailAddr, $name);    
    $mail->Subject    = "subject1";
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

Comment: swiftmailer? eregi_replace() is deprecated. You dont check your post-variables.

Comment: i have remove "eregi_replace()" but nothing change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Note:*** Since you didn't mention it in your question, I am assuming that you are using PHPMailer class. It would be a good idea to update the question with this information.

The **AddAddress()** function, as the name implies, **adds** new addresses to the recipients list while at the same time keeping the previously added addresses.

**Solution:**

You'll have to use **clearAllRecipients()** function before you added the recipient address for the second email at the line *`$mail->AddAddress($emailAddr, $name);`*. Your final code in that part should look like this:

`$mail->clearAllRecipients();
$mail->AddAddress($emailAddr, $name);`

Ref: http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_clearAllRecipients

There are many other similar useful functions mentioned there. Please check. Also, have a look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952441/phpmailer-how-do-you-remove-recipients) and the answer. It will help you understand the problem more.

Hope my answer helps.