# Foreach loop in PHP repeating every intended result for each element in it, what am I missing?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I want to send each email a specific message, but the look is not working as expected, because the first email address receives her corresponding message, but the second email address receives two messages (the one for the first and the one for the second email in the list), and the third email receives three emails, each email with the message for each email.

This is my code:

```
$messages = array(
    'x1@gmail.com'=>'message for X1',
    'x2@gmail.com'=>'message for X2',
    'x3@gmail.com'=>'message for X3'
);

foreach ($messages as $key => $value) {
    $mail->addAddress($key);
    $mail->Subject = $value;
    $mail->send();
}
```

I tried `unset($razones[$key]);` before the loop ends, so the item is extracted from the array before continues, but still the output is not working.

This is what I get:

> X1 receives 3 mails: message for X1 message for X2 message for X3
>
> X2 receives 2 mails: message for X2 message for X3
>
> X3 receives 1 mail: message for X3

The intended result I think is pretty obvious:

> X1 receives 1 email: message for X1
>
> X2 receives 1 email: message for X2
>
> X3 receives 1 email: message for X3

I know that there is something silly not working in my logic, and staring right at my face, but I cannot see it after many hours of trying on my own.

I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: Instantiate `$mail` in each iteration.

Comment: Short answer, do `$mail->clearAddresses()` at the beginning of each loop, otherwise you're just adding the new email address to the mailer each time, not removing the old ones.

Comment: It's adding man can't you see: $mail->addAddress($key);

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952441/phpmailer-how-do-you-remove-recipients